# What is the user/password for `sudo mysql` on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, mysql

When I installed mysql, I didn't write down the mysql root user password. I can get to the mysql prompt with just `sudo mysql`. However, `mysql -u root -p` does not work with the system's root password. I need to run a script, `automysqlbackup`, and it uses `mysql -u root -p` to login to mysql and create the backups.

There are a lot of pages on the Internet for resetting the mysql root password, but I am worried that I will lose the ability to use `sudo mysql`, and will have to always use `mysql -u -p` if I reset the root password for mysql.

Is there a way to find out what user/password mysql is using for `sudo mysql`? Will I trash the `sudo mysql` command if I change the mysql root password?

Thanks!

Comment: Default won't have a root password.  Default in 20.04 and later is user socket level trust, so `sudo mysql` executes as the root user and thereby local-auths from the user level with the socket.  You'd have to change the passwords, and then use `sudo mysql -u root- p` and then provide the password every time for the `root` user in MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! In order to save the `sudo mysql` option without typing the password, I just created another user `backup-mysql` with a password, granted all privileges on all databases, and use that user and password for the backup script.